# Accessing external context within lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda

This might be a pretty nooby question, but I wasn't able to figure it out by myself.

So, I am trying to pass a lambda into the following function:

```
wiringPiISR(int pin, int mode, void (*function)())
```

... what results in this:

```
wiringPiISR(Pin::BELL, INT_EDGE_RISING, [] {});
```

... and seems to work, so I obviously can use a lambda instead of pointing to a function.

But what I actually want to do is something like that, with capturing `this` to access the function `onInterrupt(Pin pin)` in the outer context:

```
wiringPiISR(Pin::BELL_1, INT_EDGE_RISING, [this] { 
    onInterrupt(Pin::BELL_1);
});

wiringPiISR(Pin::BELL_2, INT_EDGE_RISING, [this] { 
    onInterrupt(Pin::BELL_2);
});
```

... what results in this error message:

```
No matching function for call to wiringPiISR
```

I'm not very experienced in using c++-lambdas, I know closures from many other languages, but they obviously seem to work different in c++. This capturing seems to modify the signature of the closure, but I have no idea how to fix this, or even if there is a possible solution without pointing to an "actual" function.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I assume `onInterrupt` is a member. Therefore, I'd suggest you to try `this->onInterrupt(...)`. I've seen similar behavior where the compiler was not able to compile it without explicit `this->`.

Comment: No, this does not change anything, I have already tried that. It looks like the `wiringPiISR` does not accept that closure, if I interpret the error message right.

Comment: Sorry, was not noting the function pointer within the first read. This changes things a bit (going to give an answer actually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ lambdas are only convertible to function pointers if there is **no capture** (and you are capturing `this` as stated).

Also refer to the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section `5.1.2`:

> The closure type for a lambda-expression **with no lambda-capture** has a
>   public non-virtual non-explicit const **conversion function to pointer
>   to function** having the same parameter and return types as the closure
>   type’s function call operator.

As a solution, you could use `std::function` instead of the function pointer.